# handling a different types of Timestamp in Dask or Pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do the following operation-:

`(pd.to_datetime('2014-04-15 09:30:39+02:00') - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01"))`

but it throws this error-: `TypeError: Cannot subtract tz-naive and tz-aware datetime-like objects.`

this line of code works with the following timestamps

```
1. (pd.to_datetime('2014-04-14 00:00:00') - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01"))
2. (pd.to_datetime('2014-04-15 09:30') - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01"))
3. (pd.to_datetime('2014-04-15') - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01"))
```

is there any good way to convert the timestamp into the 1st (as there are three)?

what could be the reason for this error?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given the default behavior for [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and timestamp() is to assume UTC when set to True, unless specified otherwise, and given in pd.Timestamp you are not specifying it, therefore, assuming UTC, you can use:

```
(pd.to_datetime('2014-04-15 09:30:39+02:00') - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01",tz='UTC'))
```

Comment: Thank you. There are multiple timestamps. so this modification does not work for other ones. is there any other way to solve this?  I have 6 columns (it contains different timestamps)